# Why can I access my router from one ISP but not the other?

Tags: wireless-networking

My ISP is Airtel for the router; a [TP-Link TL-MR6400](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/products/details/cat-4691_TL-MR6400.html).

When I want to access my router remotely, it allows me when am using Airtel’s internet connection only.

But when I change my internet connection to Orange (ISP), Airtel denies me access to the router. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your provider has routing or firewall rules in effect to block access from outside their network, or there may be firewall rules on the router itself.

Comment: Is it an unusual port? It does sound like rule based filtering. Can you change the port?  If you must do this, be aware that this will attract brute force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like rules based filtering.
It may be the ISP, and it is likely based upon the default port the router ships with. They may not want people to be running web servers over the GSM network, even simple ones.

Before contacting your ISP, or their community, have a look at the firewall settings on the router to rule that out.

If you can momentarily change the port to 8443 and check the HTTPS option, see if that works. You should not leave this as 443 or any known ports for attacks.

Do you really need to access this from the world?  Ideally you would access this from a "bastion" desktop or proxy on the local network. (By Remote Desktop or SSH).

See also if you can VPN in to the router, which will put you on the local network, and get in that way.  It may not be possible, some of these features are mutually exclusive.